# TeamCity и загадочная ситуация с MsBuild :)

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, msbuild

Ситуация следующая:

- есть солюшн Вижуал Студио на шарпе. С 6~ установленными нюгетами. Один из которых "комбинированный" - SeleniumWebDrivers, который в себя включает целую кучу дочерних нюгетов. (плохо, но что поделать). Все компилируется ОК.
- Есть проэкт тимСити. С ним проблема -- он НЕ компилируется говоря что не хватает некоего нюгета.(который по-факту входит в тот "комбинированный", хотя и версии 23.0)

> C:\Program
>   Files\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d6c490522dc25c8a\Ifrit\BotAgent.Ifrit.csproj(158,
>   5): This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.2.24.0.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets.

утановка Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.2.24.0.0 ничего не меняет.

Как так может быть, что бы вижуалка все хавала, а вот тим сити сбилдить теми же средствами вижуалки проект уже не может?

Comment: Я поставил минус вопросу за слэнг ("хавала"), завуалированный мат и _чрезмерные_ кальки с английского в профжаргоне.

Comment: А где именно скрытый мат? И почему я не знаю про скрытый мат в моем же тексте? :) Особенно, если учесть, что сам я не матерюсь.по жизни :)

Comment: Завуалированный мат я удалил. Вы считаете "я не матерюсь" явно, но употребляете его в неявном виде. Почитайте хотя бы это: http://irc.lv/qna/help#faq-general-q11 про "Слова, образованные в похожей по фонетике с матерными словами манере"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не часто, но наблюдал такую ошибку в teamcity.
Именно, что локально собирается без проблем, а тим сити падает с ошибкой -- и на любых в общем-то пакетах.

Если открыть проблемный проект солюшена и посмотреть в references на путь (path) то все нормальные пакеты ведут в папку packages, а тот, который проблемный - в папку out.

Формально, локально всё работает -- пакеты есть, всё ставится. А тимсити, выполняя по шагам build так же формально пакет не находит.

Как лечить? Удалить-добавить заново пакет, проверить, что путь ведёт в папку packages.

Причины бага. Я грешу на Resharper, при каких-то вариантах (не всегда, поэтому не знаю точно как воспроизвести баг) он подтягивает ссылки как-то криво. Поскольку у меня такой баг выскакивает раз в несколько месяцев, то до багрепорта не дошло дело.

На 2017 студии пока не видел такого бага.

Update. Тут мы сегодня у коллеги ковыряли такой же случай. У него немного другая проблема была. При коммите в TFS улетела только часть файлов - и локально у него на компе в папке packages лежит два пакета, а в TFS только один, старый. Вот и отсутствие пакета на сервере.